# Keeping ui-btn-active class in a jquery mobile navbar after transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I don't quite know why this is default but it looks like the ui-btn-active class is removed after a transition in JQM if the navbar is used to fire a transition to another page.

As per JQM demo docs: "If this is a link to another page, the class will be removed again after the transition has completed."

I don't have text on the navbar for a cleaner UI so I can't use the data-title = text of anchor method to restore the ui-btn-active class. Adding the ui-state-persist class to each navbar anchor doesn't work either.

The ui-btn-active class is added to the page I've just navigated to if I click/tap on that page's link in the navbar.

I thought a simple

```
$('[data-role="navbar"] a').on('click', function() {

    $('.navbaranchorclass').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
    $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
});
```

would work but something in JQM obviously gets in the middle and causes the class to disappear after transition.

So my question is does anyone know how to get the ui-btn-active class to remain after page transition?

Comment: have you added `ui-state-persist` class to that anchor?

Comment: yes it didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Here is a solution to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29516654/5394593